# Pagination - Get all items from DB and then paginate, or get "pages" of items?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, doctrine-orm

I'm currently developing a Zend Framework project, using Doctrine as ORM.

I ran into the typical situation where you have to show a list of items (around 400) in a table, and of course, I don't want to show them all at once.
I've already used [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) before (only some basic usage), but i always used to get all the items from the DB, and then paginate them, but now it doesn't feel quite right.

My question is this: is it better to get **all items** from DB first and then "paginate" them, or to get **"pages" of items** as they are requested? which would have a larger impact on performance?

Comment: Edit: Getting all the items would have the largest impact on performance, but how much would obviously depend on the ammount of items.

The easiest solution i found when using limit and still need the total count is SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS [columns] FROM [table] and then SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rows afterwards to get the "real count" without the limit.

Comment: thanks @Mick, but that doesn't really answer my question on which is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it is better to get a part of the data and then paginate through them.

1. If you get All the data from a DB you paginate with the help of JavaScript.
   The first opening of the page will take a long time (for 400 rec. is OK).
   Browser has a limited memory. If a user opens up a lot of tabs in the browser 
   and you take a lot of memory (with your data)
   this will slow down the speed of the browser and the speed of your application.
   You have only 400 records but the increase of the data happens very often.
   At worst, the whole browser may break when the page is opened.
   What if browser doesn't support JS  ...
2. If you get part of the data from DB, the only defect is if 
   a user has a very slow Internet speed(but this is the defect in the first option - in the first refresh of the page).
   If someone wants to get to another page, it will take a little bit longer than JavaScript.

The second option is better(for me) in the long run, because if it works it will work for years.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to paginate the data using client-side resources. It's usually better to do it at server-side, if you are resolved to do it programmatically (see my answer below). But I think the proposition to do it using the DB engine itself is a good idea. :)

Comment: Yes, don't necessarily :) I compared generally JS vs serverside(php) pagination ...

Comment: remember i'm using zend framework! pagination is done via Zend_Paginator, so it's not done on the client-side. and i can always use zend's cache to store the items... the thing is i have a dynamic table which can "slide" down to show many results, and you can search as well too... so i don't know if it's really neccesary to use pagination...

Comment: I now that. In Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect you can modificate Select_Qery (limit, order, where, ...). For view file you should use  PaginationControl - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.usage.rendering.example-controls

Comment: I just realize that you don't use  Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect Adapter for pagination :D ... Use it ... (Don't use array adapter!)

Comment: @tasmaniski i think you're not getting my point! we designed a table which can hold as many records as we want, with the capability to search and filter by different fields. i think maybe it's more practical and makes for a better user-experience if i put all the results in that table (which makes it extremely easy to navigate and search the records) rather than having 30 or 40 pages of records...

Comment: aaa, You thing of HTML TABLE... You can designed html table, but get result(data) with ajax... It's harder but better way ...

Answer (score 1):

The database engines are usually best suited to do the retrieval for you. So, in general, if you can delegate a data-retrieval task to the DB engine instead of doing it in-memory and using your programming language, the best bet for performance is to let the DB engine do it for you.

But also remember that if you don't configure the indices correctly or don't run a good query, you won't get the best result out of your DB engine.

However, most DB engines nowadays are capable of optimizing your queries for you and running them in their most normal form.

Comment: see my comment below and let me know what you think... i don't know if it's really neccesary to use pagination... due to the nature of the table i'm using... i could just put all items in there

Comment: I don't think that based on the nature of your UI element you'd even need pagination. I think you can do it your way, without much repercussions.

Comment: yeah... i was thinking "Keep It Simple Stupid"... it works well the way it is so i'll stick with it for now... i'll see how much it affects performance as the DB grows in size.. thanks to you both

Comment: yeah, keeping it simple and clean always beats everything else.